# Aurelia CLI and Gulp Shell

Tags: javascript, gulp, aurelia, gulp-shell

Is there a way to execute `au build` from the context of a specific folder?

My folder structure is:

```
- UI
  |-main
  | | <aurelia_project_here>
  |
  |-another
  | | <aurelia_project_here>
  |
  |-gulpfile.js
```

My `gulpfile.js` looks something like:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    shell = require('gulp-shell');

gulp.task('build-main', shell.task(['cd main', 'au build', 'cd ..']));
gulp.task('build-another', shell.task(['cd another', 'au build', 'cd ..']));

gulp.task('build', gulp.parallel('build-main', 'build-another', done => done()));
```

I need to execute the shell in the context of the respective aurelia project directories.... Unless you can specify them to the the aurelia cli

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`cwd` option](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-shell#optionscwd) of `gulp-shell`:

```
gulp.task('build-main', shell.task('au build', {cwd:'main'}));
gulp.task('build-another', shell.task('au build', {cwd:'another'}));
```